# c | c++ function return optimization

Tags: c++

how do I optimize this code? I actually want to create a function like **swap_and_return** which should return from the function if done. but I could not do it.

we can see that I wrote a lot of print values and swap values which I could've written maybe inside of **swap** function.

what are your suggestions?

```c
void swap(int *i, int *j) {
    int t = *i;
    *i = *j;
    *j = t;
}

void print_values(int x, int y, int z) {
    cout << "x=" << x << ", y=" << y << ", z=" << z << "\n";
}

float min_max(int x, int y, int z) {
    float avg = 0;
    if(x<y && x<z){
            if (y < z) {
                swap(&x, &z);
                print_values(x, y, z);
                avg = (x + z) / 2.0;
                return avg;
            }

            else {
                swap(&x, &y);
                print_values(x, y, z);
                avg = (x + y) / 2.0;
                return avg;
            }
    }

    else if(y<x && y<z){
            if (x < z) {
                swap(&y, &z);
                print_values(x, y, z);
                avg = (y + z) / 2.0;
                return avg;
            }

            else {
                swap(&y, &x);
                print_values(x, y, z);
                avg = (y + x) / 2.0;
                return avg;
            }
    }

    else if(z<y && z<x){
            if (x < y) {
                swap(&z, &y);
                print_values(x, y, z);
                avg = (z + y) / 2.0;
                return avg;
            }

            else {
                swap(&z, &x);
                print_values(x, y, z);
                avg = (z + x) / 2.0;
                return avg;
            }
    }

    return avg;
    
}

int main()
{
    float value = min_max(5, 1, 2);
    cout << value << "\n";
}
```

Comment: This not C, C++ and C are two different languages.

Comment: What is "swap_and_return"?

Comment: What to you mean by optimize? Normally that means improve the speed or memory usage, but you seem to be talking about tidying up your code. Please be clearer on what you want.

Comment: yes, I am sorry for the misunderstanding, I mean tidying up.

Comment: Strange thing about your code is why you are swapping the values. In this code `swap(&z, &y); print_values(x, y, z); avg = (z + y) / 2.0;` you'll get the same value for `avg` whether you swap `z` and `y` or not. So maybe you could just remove all the calls to `swap`.

Comment: I will actually get true values in all cases. but it's a bit hard-coded

Comment: @Kenan You have two processes here (or maybe three), find the min and max (that could be two prcoesses itself) and calculate the average. The key to tidying up your code (and reducing the repetition) is to write separate functions for those two processes.

Comment: Is the printing relevant to your problem? If it isn't, `return (std::max({x, y, z}) + std::min({x, y, z})) / 2.0f;` is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just sort the items and do your math on the smallest and largest:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void print_values(int x, int y, int z) {
    std::cout << "x=" << x << ", y=" << y << ", z=" << z << "\n";
}

float min_max(int x, int y, int z) {

    float avg = 0;
    int items[3] = { x,y,z };

    std::sort(items, items + 3);
    print_values(items[2], items[1], items[0]);
    avg = (items[0] + items[2]) / 2.0;
    return avg;
}


int main()
{
    float value = min_max(1,2,5);
    std::cout << value << "\n";
}
```

If you can't use std::sort, you can easily sort a 3-item array very quickly

```
#define SWAP_IF_GT(a, b) {if (a > b) {int tmp=a;a=b;b=tmp;}}

float min_max(int x, int y, int z) {
    float avg = 0;

    SWAP_IF_GT(x,y);
    SWAP_IF_GT(y,z);
    SWAP_IF_GT(x,y);

    print_values(z,y,x);
    avg = (x+z) / 2.0;
    return avg;
}
```

Comment: what I mean by optimization is I'm repeating myself, how do I reduce it?

Comment: thank you so much, I'll probably need to change sort() function to my own function because they would not accept.

Comment: @Kenan - Updated to show you how easy it is to sort  a 3 items inline with a macro.

Comment: Why using `MACRO`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to swap, print (`x`, `y`, `z`) and calculate the average in every `if.. else`. Find out the `largest` and `smallest` in `x`, `y` and `z` and then swap the `largest` and `smallest` element and return the average of `largest` and `smallest` element from `min_max()`.

Implementation:

```
#include <iostream>

void print_values(int x, int y, int z) {
    std::cout << "x=" << x << ", y=" << y << ", z=" << z << std::endl;
}

float min_max (int x, int y, int z) {
    int& largest = ((x >= y) && (x >= z)) ? x : (((y >= x) && (y >= z)) ? y : z);
    int& smallest = ((x <= y) && (x <= z)) ? x : (((y <= x) && (y <= z)) ? y : z);

    std::swap (smallest, largest);

    print_values(x, y, z);

    return (smallest + largest) / 2.0;
}

int main() {
    float value = min_max(5, 1, 2);
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```